# How %d works for "" in string ? Result: 4210704

Tags: c, integer, printf, string-literals, conversion-specifier

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%c code\n", 'C');
    printf("%d", "");
    return 0;
}
```

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d", 3); /* result 3 */
    printf("%d", '3'); /* result 51, because 3 is char (from ASCII table) */
    printf("%d", ""); /
    return 0;
}
```

I'm a beginner at C. I read "C Programming Absolute beginner's Guide" Thurd Edition by Greg Pery and Dean Miller. There are examples of %c  %d and %f . I've started experiment with them and noticed thing that i can't explain how it was made.
So i tried these examples with %d and understood how first two work. For last one i have ideas how computer read this but I ain't sure how all 0s and 1s combine together.
If you have explanation of that, I will glad to response you back)))

Comment: `printf("%d", "");` prints low half of address of the empty string (`"\0"`).

Comment: The compiler should **warn** you that `printf("%d", "");` is incorrect. The output will make no sense.

Comment: Most modern compilers will warn about this type issue. If you don't get warning, check your compiler settings, or switch to newer compiler if such setting is not available.

Comment: Weather Vane, try it, my output is always show 4210704 and idk why)))

Comment: user694733, I downloaded Code::Blox, how settings can be unavailable for this simple code?

Comment: Code::Blocks works with multiple compilers, but typically comes with GCC based compiler. If that is the case for you, then you should check compiler settings to make sure that compiler option `-Wall` is used during compilation. (Or `-Wall -pedantic -Wextra` for even more error checking.)

Comment: user694733, thank you so much for your advice. I appreciate it)))

Answer (score 6):

This call

```
printf("%d", "");
```

has undefined behavior.  From the C Standard (7.21.6.1 The fprintf function):

> 9 If a conversion specification is invalid, the behavior is
> undefined.288) **If any argument is not the correct type for the
> corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.**

If you want to output a pointer (in this call of `printf` the string literal having array type `char[1]` is implicitly converted to a pointer to its first element of the type `char *`) as an integer then use header `<inttypes.h>` and write

```
#include <inttypes.h>

//...

printf("%" PRIdPTR "\n", ( intptr_t )( void * )"");
```

Or to output the string literal as a pointer you could write

```
printf( "%p\n", ( void * )"" );
```

Here is a demonstration program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main( void )
{
    printf( "%08" PRIXPTR "\n", ( uintptr_t )( void * )"" );
    printf( "%p\n", ( void * )"" );
}
```

Its output might look like

```
00F19B38
00F19B38
```

There is used macro `PRIXPTR` instead of `PRIdPTR` to output the pointer as an integer in the hexadecimal representation the same way as in case of using the conversion specifier `p` for pointers.

Comment: Thank you so much))) It looks like what i can't get now ahah. Are PRIXPTR and PRIdPTR format specifiers?

Comment: I should read more about undefined behavior)))

Comment: @Gribnik2000 `PRIXPTR` and `PRIdPTR` are macros that expand to string literals for concatenation with other string literals. The strings literal depends on how the corresponding integer type is converted by the *default argument promotions*. For example, if `intptr_t` values are converted to `long long int` by the default argument promotions, `PRIdPTR` would expand to the string literal `"lld"`.

Comment: The `"%" PRIdPTR` specifier expects an argument of type `intptr_t`, not `void *`, so the code requires additional type casts from `void *` to `intptr_t` to avoid UB. (Ditto for `"%" PRIXPTR` and `uintptr_t`.)

Comment: Ian Abbott, thank you so much for your explanation. I appreciate it)))

Answer (score 0):

`""` is an empty string, not a character - i.e., it's a pointer with some fancy syntax sugar around it. Since you don't control where this string is allocated, it's allocated to an arbitrary location in the memory, and when using `%d` to print it, you get the offset from the beginning of the segment that contains it.

Note that on multiple executions of the same program the first two `printf` statements will always print the same values (3 and 51, as you noted), but the third one may print a different number every time.

Comment: Isn't the  shown code simply Undefined Behaviour?

Comment: Thank you for your answer and "fancy syntax sugar around it" sounds really interesting))) because number 4210704 always displays from ""

Comment: Yunnosch, I'll look into this issue)

Answer (score 0):

`""` is a pointer to (i.e. memory address of) a single null byte acting as string terminator for your empty string, somewhere in memory. You see a truncated version of the memory address here. Note the result also won't always be the same, especially when you modify other parts of your program, because that empty string won't always be located at the same address.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. I've never fought about truncated version. I know that only for float numbers in Python))) But the actually result is the same: 4210704 for "". Maybe you meant something else but i will get it later, i promise)))

Answer (score 0):

> How %d works for "" in string ?

Short answer is that it doesn't; `%d` expects its corresponding argument to be an `int`, and a string literal is not an `int`.  The behavior is *undefined*, meaning that neither the compiler nor the runtime environment are required to handle the situation in any particular way.  You'll get some kind of output (usually), just don't expect that output to be meaningful in any way.

A string literal like `""` is an array expression; its type is "1-element array of `char`".  Under most circumstances, an array expression is converted, or "decays", to a pointer expression and the value of the pointer is the address of the first element of the array.  So what you're actually passing to `printf` is a `char *` value.

You told `printf` to expect an `int`, but you gave it a `char *`.  In practice, most implementations will attempt to interpret that pointer value as an `int` and format it for display as a decimal integer.

Problem is that on many modern implementations, a pointer value can't be represented in an `int` so only part of the value is converted and displayed.  Some implementations may pass `int` arguments in specific registers rather than on the stack, so `printf` may not even be looking in the right place for the value and convert some random bit pattern.

Again, the behavior is undefined so *any* result is equally "correct".

Comment: John Bode, thank you so much for your explanation. I appreciate it)))